# OpenCart maintenance mode 503 error

Tags: apache, opencart, directadmin

I install `directadmin` with `CB2` + `Apache` + `MariaDB 10.1.31` + `PHP 5.6.34`.
When I upload OpenCart and enable maintenance mode, Apache shows the 503 error page instead of `maintenance.tpl`.

I checked the `catalog/controller/common/maintenance.php` and found the following code:

```
if ($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
    $this->response->addHeader('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
} else {
    $this->response->addHeader('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable');
}

$this->response->addHeader('Retry-After: 3600');
```

I think the problem is that Apache does not handle the 503 Header correctly. When I change the web server to LiteSpeed, it is ok.

To check you can compare these two versions of the site. Both of them have the maintenance mode enabled, but:

The first is OK - http://takjens.com/

The second is not - http://server3.lammer.ir/

Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry but what is CB2? It's not a tag here on SO, I get nothing but Crate & Barrel when I search it and there's nothing helpful in the wikipedia disambiguation.

Comment: CustomBuild 2  http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=44743

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has something to do with your apache config.  What version of Apache is it?  And do you have `ErrorDocument 503` directive declared somewhere in your config?

Answer (score 0):

Here LiteSpeed has custom error page configured, while Apache shows default 503 error page, as defined in the response header.

To make Apache display the custom error page, do the following:

1. Add the custom error page directive to the Apache configuration or into the `.htaccess` file for the domain. Specify the path to the `maintenance.tpl` file relatively to the configured `ServerRoot`:

   `ErrorDocument 503 /path/to/maintenance.tpl`
2. `.tpl` file extension is not something that Apache can serve by default. I order to process it properly, the correct file type should be specified for this extension either in Apache configuration or via `.htaccess` file:

   `AddType text/html        tpl`

Comment: this is not problem.
please check header of these sites with Curl then open in browsers.

http://takjens.com/

http://server3.lammer.ir/